# Reading data from a RS232 port with RFID

Tags: c#, hardware

**UPDATE**

I'm reading an `RFID Card`, and signing it's value into my `textbox.text`.
It's working in the first time I pass the card in my `RFID Reader`, but form the second time I pass the card, instead it shows the whole card's id on my `textbox.text`, it's showing only the LAST letter of the card's id. Sometimes you can see the whole number appear and vanish very fast on the textbox, but from the second time you pass the card, only the last letter remain in the textbox.
What may be causing this ?

Here's my current code:

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO.Ports;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace RFID_Reader
{
    public partial class PortaSerial : Form
    {
        private SerialPort porta_serial = new SerialPort("COM1", 9600, Parity.None, 8, StopBits.One);


        public PortaSerial()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void PortaSerial_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                if (porta_serial.IsOpen)
                {
                    porta_serial.Close();
                }
                porta_serial.Open();
                porta_serial.DtrEnable = true;
                porta_serial.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(Recebe_Data);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new Exception(ex.Message);
            }
        }

        void Recebe_Data(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {               
                string oi = porta_serial.ReadExisting().ToString();
                SetLabel(oi);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new Exception(ex.Message);
            }
        }

        void SetLabel(String s)
        {
            try
            {
                if (this.InvokeRequired)
                {
                    this.Invoke(new Action<String>(SetLabel), s);
                    return;
                }
                textBox1.Text = RemoveSpecialCharacters(s);           
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new Exception(ex.Message);
            }
        }       

        public static string RemoveSpecialCharacters(string str)
        {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();            
            foreach (char c in str)
            {
                if ((c >= '0' && c <= '9') || (c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z') || (c >= 'a' && c <= 'z') || c == '.' || c == '_')
                {
                    sb.Append(c);
                }
            }
            return sb.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to access elements of the GUI (TextBox, Label, ...) you need to be running in the UI thread. DataReceived is running in another thread. You can change into the UI thread by Invoke like this

```
void SetLabel(String s)
{
   if (this.InvokeRequired) {
      this.Invoke (new Action<String>(SetLabel), s);
      return;
   }

   Label1.Text = s;
}
```

But beware - if you need to access different parts of the GUI (e.g. Label *and* TextBox), you should "collect" those Invoke's because every call takes some time. Also you may consider BeginInvoke instead of Invoke for not blocking the receive thread. However, you should read about those details in MSDN or google for more difficult examples.

Comment: Where do I call it ? In my `DataReceived` ?  
Also, I got this `No overload for "SetLabel" matches delegate 'System.Action'. On `this.Invoke(new Action(SetLabel), s);`

Comment: Yes, as soon as you need to write into some control's data.

Comment: Which error? There was one indeed, but I corrected the sample. Do you still have an error? Which one?

Comment: Now it's working,  but one thing, I'm receiving the card number but also some special characters. Is there a way to filter to only sign to the textbox1.text letters ?

Comment: There are numerous ways to do that, actually. Some more complicated than others... The simplest may be to use String.Replace - if you know which are the special chars, that is.

Comment: I found it. Thank you JEffRSon!

Comment: `s = s.Replace("\r", "").Replace("\n", "");` could help.

Comment: now, if I pass the card for the second time, it only shows the first number of the card o.O

Comment: Hard to say without knowing that special reader and how you're working with exactly...

Comment: Well, with every Receive event you overwrite the label. So if the ID is broken into parts you'll see only the last part. Is there some end-of-text character? Only if you received this eot, your input is complete and you may proceed. As a first test you could try to append all your traffic to a multiline textbox, so you can see everything that came in.

Comment: Look, from the second time, it ALWAYS shows the `Last char of the card's ID`...  Normally it has some special characters like: `A1B2C3\n\rX` , Where X = Something like a four-square, you know ? Like an unrecognized character... That's why I'm using the `RemoveSpecialCharacter` method. Another interesting thing is, if I debug the app using BreakPoints, it ALWAYS WORKS, but without breakpoints I got the problem that I told you...

Comment: If using breakpoints, the serial communication has "enough" time to collect all characters. Have you tried the TextBox-append-approach? On a second view - in your question you write about the first character, now you say it's the last?

Comment: On my first card, the first and last character was the same, I tested with a differente card, then I realized it was the `last` char. I'm sorry. I already edited it in my question...

Comment: Ok, with the `textbox1.AppendText("Text");` it's kind of working, but as you know how `Append` works, its accumulating the ids...
How may I work around it ?

Comment: It depends... If `A1B2C3\n\rX` is your protocol definition you could wait until you have received this many characters and only then output the ID. Or you could read until you're sure you have `\n\r` (.Contains may help) and forget about the `X` (which may be some checksum). Or set `porta_serial.NewLine` and use `porta_serial.ReadLine()` and forget about the `X`. The point is to collect all characters until the protocols eot character and only then output the ID.

Comment: The `A1B2C3\n\rX` is the value I get when I pass the `mifare card` on the `RFID Reader` that is connected on `RS232 port`. Acctually if I do not do any filter the value is `XA1B2C3\n\rX`. I don't want the `X`.  
I Just didn't get it yet what to do =\

Comment: You need some buffer (String or better StringBuilder) where you write all received data. Then check whether there is `\n\r` in this buffer. Copy data including `\n\r` to some string that you can write to the label and remove the same data from your buffer. Check again if there's `\n\r` (maybe there`ve been two cards read) a.s.o. If you don't find `\n\r` do nothing.

Comment: As I told you, from the second time I pass the card, the whole ID appears and vanish really fast. I thought maybe it has something to do with the BUffer ?
All I know is that I added `Thread.Sleep(100);` And now it's working. I just really want to know what could be causing that problem...

Comment: Just one more thing. Is there a way to fires the `Button_Click Event` When reading the data from `RS232 port` ? It works automatically with `USB` ;s

Comment: Sorry - what button, what USB?

Comment: SOrry for didnt explain it right. When I pass my card on the my `RFID READER` that is connected by `USB` it fires the Button_Click Event automatically. But with the other `RFID Reader` That is connected by `RS232 port` It doesnt. IS there a way to fire the button_Click Event when reading by the RS232 port ?

Comment: Hmmm - maybe the USB reader is working like an HID mouse/keyboard? However, this is getting too far away from topic.

Answer (score 0):

In your Form1_Load method, you use `port` to refer to your `SerialPort` object, but in your event handler, you use `porta_serial`.

Comment: Sorry, MyBad. It was correct, I just forgot to change here.  
The problem was, I was using a software that was using the `COM1` port... I Just don't know why it didn't fire an error.  Now it's reading... Thanks @Steve

Comment: But now, I'm getting a diferent error. I'll update my question